# Reading and multiply in parallel

Tags: c++, c, io, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am developing some software in C/C++ for a linear algebra tool that involves multiplying large matrices (>500GB) "out of core," in the sense that they are never fully loaded into the memory.  As such, I will load it in batches, and perform the multiplication piecewise (several rows at a time) using Intel's MKL gemm functions.

I wanted to know if there are any good patterns to parallelize the reading and the multiplication.  Say the machine has 8 cores.  I would like one core to be reading in the batches, while the other 7 cores are performing the multiplication.  Since you can only efficiently read data with one core, it would involve the 7 others waiting idly while the batch is read.   As such, I would like to parallelize them such that the multiplication is happening while the reading is happening.

I'm not really sure how this would look: would I load 1000 rows and then let the gemm functions take over while another core is loading another 1000 rows?

Comment: Does not MKL decide how to do something effectively?

Comment: MKL will do the matrix multiplication effectively--to my knowledge, it is not involved in reading the matrix (i.e. the input phase).  If the problem were not "out of core" then of course, MKL paralelizes the multiplication on its own.

Comment: Not sure at all that you have an interest in using completely optimized matrix code in that situation. Your bottleneck will be IO, so there is not much advantage of having your CPU heat up during the short bursts in which you happen to have the data available. This is just a vaste of energy.

Comment: @JensGustedt, I'm not sure that's actually true.  Reading two `n` x `n` matrices is `O(n^2)`, whereas multiplying them is `O(n^3)`.  Even with vastly different coefficients, the computation must at some point become the more costly part, and we're talking about very large `n`.

Comment: On the other hand, if "out of core" implies that parts or all of the input matrices must be read multiple times each, then the I/O might scale worse than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, IO to disk is somewhere 1000 times slower than computation. So you'd have to have 1000 instructions per word that you load before things can start to pay off.

Comment: @JensGustedt for matrices > 500GB each, as specified, there are in excess of 80000 rows and columns per matrix (assuming square matrices stored as closely-packed, raw 64-bit doubles).  If indeed each datum can be read once only, then that's easily in the regime where the computation may be more expensive than the I/O.  I have come to doubt whether multiple reads of the same data can be avoided, however.